# Nikon WiFi transfer protocol (MTP, Hacking, Ports)

Tags: networking, mtp

This is a copy of [a post I made to photo.stackexchange.com](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/70345/how-can-i-directly-browse-or-transfer-pictures-from-ios-without-using-the-nikon). I felt I should put it here due to the more technical side of the question, and it barely relating to photography.

I have a Nikon D5300 with built in WiFi. I'm interested in tinkering/hacking with its network protocol and transferring photos wirelessly.

After looking into the network protocols and ports, I found [this Nikon Network guide](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D4NWG_En_01.pdf). It talks about how you can use FTP on some WiFi chips in different camera models, but I'm not sure if it includes mine.

I know there are two ports used for the connection; one is 15740 to transfer the photos, and one is 5353 to connect. I also found that the chip uses the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP).

Is there a way I can directly browse or transfer pictures from Ubuntu?